# CakePHP 3 : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2 and in `login()` action, want to allow login to only those whose status is `verified = 1`

```
public function login()
    {
      if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->query('provider')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
          if ($user->verified != 1) {   // LINE 6
            $this->Flash->error(__('You have not yet verified your account. Please check your email to verify your account before login'), [
              'params' => [
                'userId' => $user->id,   // LINE 9
              ],
              ['escape' => false]
            ]);
            $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
          }
          $this->Auth->setUser($user);
          $this->_setCookie();
          $this->Flash->success('Login Success');
          return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
      }
    }
```

But this gives error as

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 6]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 9]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/argoSystems/projects/project_01/site/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:746) [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 572]
Warning (2): session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 576]
```

> NOTE : line number has been changed to meet code snippets

Comment: Have you changed the lines of the error notices to match your snippet? If you do something like that, then please tell people, otherwise they might just ignore you, as figuring out where the line numbers may point to is a pretty tedious task. That being said, you really need to start learning a bit more about PHP and debugging basics, as this is a really, really trivial problem, and figuring out why it happens is as simple as reading the API docs for `AuthComponent::identifiy()`, and debugging what exactly `$user` is.

Comment: Thank you @ndm debugging $user gives correct parameters and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem. This is my updated `login()` method.

```
public function login()
    {
      if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->query('provider')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
          $this->Auth->setUser($user);
          if ($this->Auth->user('verified') != 1) { 
            $this->Flash->error(__('You have not yet verified your account. Please check your email to verify your account before login'), [
              'params' => [
                'userId' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
              ],
              ['escape' => false]
            ]);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
          }
          $this->_setCookie();
          $this->Flash->success('Login Success');
          return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could have solved this easily! Change line 6 for example from

`if ($user->verified != 1) {   // LINE 6`

to

`$user["verified"] != 1) {   // LINE 6`